# Which vector is perpendicular to the normal vector

Tags: calculus

Which vector is perpendicular to the normal vectors of the planes 2x+4y-z=10 and 3x-2y+2z=5

1.(5,2,1)

2.(6,-7,-16)

3.(-14,6,7)

4.6,-8,-2)

is the answer 1,2,3 or 4

Comment: its 2. I tried the dot product and got 0 thank you

Comment: I have three rather different directions  that you can go,  Find the line that is in common with those planes.  As it lies in both planes, its direction is perpendicular to the normal vector of both.  Option 2:  Take the dot product of each of the 4 optioons given, with the normal vectors of the planes.  Option 3:  find the cross product of the normal vectors of the planes.

Answer (score 1):

Given plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ a normal vector is $<a,b,c>$.

So you need a vector perpendicular to both $<2,4,-1>$ and $<3,-2,2>$.

Another way to do this besides taking the dot product of each of your choice vectors with these two vectors is to take the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the two normal vectors:

$$<2,4,-1> \times <3,-2,2> = <6,-7,-16>.$$

A (nonzero) cross product is always perpendicular to the two vectors crossed.

In this case you get your answer directly, but even if not the answer will be this vector times some constant scalar.